# Place element on the right corner of a window

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to add a close button to a window in `HTML`, and I would like the button to float over the winodw like in this example : http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/ (the second example)

So I added a `div` to my `HTML` code lie this :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<body class="din">
    <h1>MyWindow</h1>
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <div id="coucou"></div>
    <img id="close" src="img/close.png" value="Close Window" onclick="closeWindow()"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my CSS :

```
#close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1em;
    right: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

the button appears on the window in the right top, but not exactly on the top corner. What should I add to make it appear exactly on the corner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesnt appear exactly in the top right, because you have set the top and right styles to something other than zero:

```
#close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; /* <--- set to zero, 1em = the inherited font size, which will offset it */
    right: 0;/* <--- set to zero, 1em = the inherited font size, which will offset it */
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Yesc changing the values of top and right attributes places the button in the top corner of the window, but the close button is still inside the window. The effect I am looking for is placing the button ON the right top corner, if you see what I mean ?

Comment: @akari - you may want to provide more code and/or a jsfiddle, the problem isnt reproducible given the code available

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
#close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hqNsR/1/)**

**[Full Screen Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hqNsR/1/embedded/result/)**